# NodeJS - How to return a PDF from a Base64 without saving the file on server?

Tags: node.js, file, pdf, fs

Here is my scenario:

- I have an application built in Node with Express;
- I have an external API that returns a Base64 PDF file;
- I have to get this Base64 and open the file for the user;
- I am unable to save the PDF on server.

I've tried many ways and I can't open the file to the user.

Ways I've tried:

```
const buff = Buffer.from(myBase64, 'base64');
const file = fs.writeFileSync('boleto.pdf', buff, { encoding: 'base64' });

try {
  res.setHeader('Content-Length', file.size);
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/pdf');
  res.setHeader('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename=boleto.pdf');
} catch (e) {
  return res.status(404).send({ error: e, message: 'File does not exist.', statusCode: 404 });
}
```

```
const buff = Buffer.from(myBase64, 'base64');
const file = fs.writeFileSync('boleto.pdf', buff, { encoding: 'base64' });

try {
  res.contentType('application/pdf');
  return res.status(200).sendFile('boleto');
} catch (e) {
  return res.status(404).send({ error: e, message: 'File does not exist.', statusCode: 404 });
}
```

```
const buff = Buffer.from(myBase64, 'base64');
const file = fs.readFileSync(buff, { encoding: 'base64' });

try {
  res.contentType('application/pdf');
  return res.status(200).sendFile(file);
} catch (e) {
  return res.status(404).send({ error: e, message: 'File does not exist.', statusCode: 404 });
}
```

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 8):

The proper way to do this here would be to call the service and direct the base64 string response to a decoding stream, then pipe that to the response output. That would save you having to wait for files to download or for the `string` -> `byte` translation to finish.

However if you are only dealing with small files (<1MB) and you dont have to handle traffic from thousands of concurrent requests its probably fine to just download the base64 string and use `Buffer.from(base64str, 'base64')` to decode it before passing it onwards.

This "minimal implementation" approach goes something like this:

```js
const axios = require('axios'); // or any other similar library (request, got, http...)

const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

router.get('/invoice/:id.pdf', async (req, res) => {
  // Here is the call to my external API to get a base64 string.
  const id = req.params.id;
  const response = await axios.get('https://myfileapi.domain.com/file/?id=' + id);
  const base64str = response.data;

  // Here is how I get user to download it nicely as PDF bytes instead of base64 string.
  res.type('application/pdf');
  res.header('Content-Disposition', `attachment; filename="${id}.pdf"`);
  res.send(Buffer.from(base64str, 'base64'));
});

module.exports = router;
```

Note that there is no authentication here to block other users accessing this file, if you want authentication you'll have to handle that separately.